# socket server nginx redirect buy domain income

Tags: sockets, nginx

i run socket server and i use nginx to redirect to random port
its possible with nginx redirect to random ports and by domain income request for example lets say 
a-domain.com:48600
b-domain.com:48600

when request income from a-domain go to **localhost:1001** or **localhost:1002**
when request is from b-domain go to **localhost:10012** or **localhost:10013** its possible this with nginx?

this is my config at the moment working with one domain

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


stream {
 server {

        listen     48600;
        proxy_pass stream_backend;
  }

 upstream stream_backend {
        least_conn;
        server 12.0.0.9:1001;
        server 12.0.0.9:1002;
        server 12.0.0.9:1003;
        server 12.0.0.9:1004;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is get second IP ....